Ubuntu 24.04.1 - Gnome 46 : Hide applications opened on other workspace in the launcher as well
I was looking for a way to hide windows highlighted with a dot on the launcher which is opened on different workspace.
The answers provided here and here shows how to hide windows of other workspace
from Alt + Tab switcher. I followed those answers and those solutions didn't hide the windows highlighted with a dot in the launcher (Left panel of icons). And clicking on one of the icons which has a opened window on other workspace will drag you to respective workspace.
Thank you.
